# Get size (length) of attachment using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, rest

I'm trying to get the file size of attachments using SharePoint designer. I have the correct url but when calling the web service i get the count of items returned = 0 .

The url i use is :

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Lists/RALLILessons/Attachments/28170/test.pdf')
```

Here is a screenshot of the steps used :

[image]

Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong. On previous steps i use this rest api call :

```
https://tennant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RALLI-Lessons')/Items(24452)/attachmentfiles
```

to get the Server Relative Url which i then use to construct the rest api call for the file properties.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? Should i use the d/results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, get the attach file ServerRelativeUrl  with the Rest EndPoint below:

https://kevindemo167.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('TestList')/items(1)?$expand=AttachmentFiles
[image]

Then access the file and properties with this Url:

https://kevindemo167.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/Developer/Lists/TestList/Attachments/1/Untitled.png')

Note, the serveraltiveurl should be the same as the url got from first EndPoint, and there is a properties named "Length", it's the attachment file length/size：
[image]

In the workflow, Please use "d/Length" to get the file length from the response Dictionary:
[image]

Comment: Much appreciated it for the reply. I actually found out the solution using Postman . I could see that there is no results nodes , and i use d/length. However thanks again . I will mark your post as the answer